# Play audio from a GenericEventArgs<Stream>

Tags: c#, audio, asp.net-core

Is there any alternatives for me instead of using SoundPlayer? i am trying to rewamp my project for .net core which doesnt support system.media.

background on project: I am sending text from my mobile app to my c# app and the text that is received is being played up with "SoundPlayer" through a text to speech api.

I tried with NAudio only but i didn't get it to work at all.

this is the code that is working that i am trying to rewamp to .net core use. If i send for example the text "Hello" to my c# app. The SoundPlayer plays up "hello".

```
    public void PlayAudio(object sender, GenericEventArgs<Stream> args)
    {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(args.EventData);
        player.PlaySync();
        args.EventData.Dispose();
    }
```

This is the output from that comes from Args.EventData if i console.writeline it "System.Net.Http.StreamContent+ReadOnlyStream"

Comment: Not a duplicate stalker. That is a post asking for a NAudio converter. This is not, Asking for a general converter.

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here:" ye no.